# postgresl SQL statement displays dates outside the interval

Tags: sql, postgresql, utc

On RHEL, the date/time at the command prompt is in UTC time.
I query my table for dates in the last hour, but it returns me other dates/times.  I don't know if it is timezone related but I am super confused how to work with it

```
select to_char(update_dt, 'DD Mon YYYY HH12:MI'),data 
from mytable
where update_dt > current_date - interval '1' hour


      to_char      |   data
-------------------+----------------
 07 May 2020 12:37 | blah
 07 May 2020 12:37 | blah
 07 May 2020 12:37 | blah
 07 May 2020 12:37 | blah
 07 May 2020 12:37 | blah
 07 May 2020 05:23 | huh
 07 May 2020 05:23 | huh
 07 May 2020 05:22 | huh

[root@ip-172-31-1-28 ~]# date
Thu May  7 13:25:03 UTC 2020
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This expression:

```
where update_dt > current_date - interval '1' hour
```

goes since midnight yesterday, because `current_date` is only the *date* at midnight (at the beginning of the date).

You seem to want the *time* included:

```
where update_dt > now() - interval '1' hour
```

You can also use:

```
where update_dt > current_timestamp - interval '1' hour
```

but `now()` is easier to type.

Comment: doh of course, thanks!  Ill accept when stackoverflow lets me lol